# Information on Accordion is getting pushed out and not displaying on Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

So I created 3 accordions for a page (Item 1, Item 2, Item 3)
When you click on them, another accordion displaying the following:

- Tracking
- Address
- Date

When you click on one of them, information is suppose to display, which it does. However, when I click on Tracking and Address, Date gets push out of the way. I would love for all information to be displayed at the same time. I don't want anything "pushed out".  Can somebody tell me what I may be doing wrong?

I have provided a JS fiddle so that you can have a better idea.
https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/8qpuso01/

My file, all on one page.

```
<button class="accordion">Item 1</button>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="accordion">Tracking Number</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Address</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Date</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Item 2</button>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="accordion">Tracking Number</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Address</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Date</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<button class="accordion">Item 3</button>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="accordion">Tracking Number</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Address</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Date</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>Tracking #:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>From Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label> To Street:</label>
                <input />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
    .accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        color: orangered;
    }

        .accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        .accordion:after {
            content: '\002B';
            color: #777;
            font-weight: bold;
            float: right;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

    .active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    .panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

Comment: have a look at this https://www.codeply.com/go/h5WTUsd59R/bootstrap-4-nested-accordion